# Heuristics for this (probably) NP-complete puzzle game

Tags: algorithm, heuristics

I asked whether this problem was NP-complete on the Computer Science forum, but asking for programming heuristics seems better suited for this site. So here it goes.

You are given an NxN grid of unit squares and 2N binary strings of length N. The goal is to fill the grid with 0's and 1's so that each string appears once and only once in the grid, either horizontally (left to right) or vertically (top down). Or determine that no such solution exists. If N is not fixed I suspect this is an NP-complete problem. However are there any heuristics that can hopefully speed up the search to faster than brute force trying all ways to fill in the grid with N vertical strings?

Comment: @user2040251 N can be anything, but to make the problem at least interesting let's say N=30 to start.

Comment: I would try a constraint program solver (e.g., [z3](http://z3.codeplex.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the crossword grid filling algorithm:

- First, build 2N subsets of your 2N strings -- each subset has all the strings with a particular bit at a particular postion.  So subset(0,3) is all the strings that have a 0 in the 3rd position and subset(1,5) is all the strings that have a 1 in the 5th position.
- The algorithm is a basic brute-force depth fist search trying all possible mappings of strings to slots in the grid, with severe pruning of impossible branches
- Your search state is a set of assignments of strings to slots and a set of sets of possible assignments to the remaining slots.  The initial state has 0 assignments and 2N sets, all of which contain all 2N strings.
- At each step of the search, pick the most constrained set (the set with the fewest elements) from the set of possible sets.  Try each element of the set in turn in that slot (adding it to the assigments and removing it from the set of sets), and constrain all the remaining sets of sets by removing the chosen string and intersecting the crossing sets with subset(X,N) (computed in step 1) where X is the bit from the chosen string and N is the row/column number of the chosen string
- If you find an empty set when picking above, there is no solution with the choices so far, so backtrack up the tree to a different choice

This is still EXPTIME, but it is about as fast as you can get it.  Since the main time consuming step is the set intersections, using 2N bit binary strings for your set representation is very fast -- for N=32, the sets fit in a 64-bit word and can be intersected with a single AND instruction.  It also helps to have a POPCOUNT instruction, since you also need set sizes.

Comment: The complexity of my naive brute force is O((n^2)*2n*(2n-1)*(2n-2)*...*(n+1)). It would be nice to know what the exact worst-case complexity is for this algorithm. It looks faster but I'm not sure by how much.

Answer (score 0):

I remember programming this for my friend that had the 5x5 physical version of this game, but I used brute force back then. I can only think of this heuristic:

Consider a 4x4 map with these 8 strings (read each from left to right):

```
1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0

1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0
```

(Note that this is already solved, since the second 4 is the first 4 transposed)

**First attempt:**

We will choose columns from left to right. Since 7 of 8 strings start with `1`, we will try to put the one with most `1`s to the first column (so that we can lay rows more easily when columns are done).

In the second column, most string have 0, so you can also try putting a string with most zeros to the second row, and so on.

This i would call a *wide-1* prediction, since it only looks at one column at a time

(Possible) **Improvement:**

You can look at 2 columns at a time (a `wide-2` prediction, if i may call it like that). In this case, from the 8 strings, the most common combination of first two bits is `10` (5/8), so you would like to choose first two columns so the the combination `10` occurring as much as possible (in this case, `1111` followed by `1000` has 3 of 4 `10` at start).

(Of course you don't have to stop at 2)

**Weaknesses:**

1. I don't know if this would work. I just made it up and thought it might work.
2. If you choose to he `wide-X` prediction, the number of possibilities is exponential with `X`
3. This can absolutely fail if the distribution of combinations if even.

**What you can do:**

As i said, this game has physical 5x5 adaptation, only there you can also lay the string from right-to-left and bottom-to-top, if you found that name, you could google further. I unfortunately don't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved as a 0/1 integer linear program with O(N^2) variables and constraints. First there are variables Xij which are 1 if string i is assigned to line j (where j=1 to N are rows and j = (N+1) to 2N are columns). Then there is a variable for each square in the grid, which indicates if the entry is 0 or 1. If the position of the square is (i,j) with variable Yij then the sum of all X variables for line j that correspond to strings that have a 1 in position i is equal to Yij, and the sum of all X variables for line j that correspond to strings that have a 0 in position i is equal to (1 - Yij). And similarly for line i and position j. Finally, the sum of all X variables Xij for each string i (summed over all lines j) is equal to 1.

There has been a lot of research in speeding up solvers for 0/1 integer programming so this may be able to often handle fairly large N (like N=100) for many examples. Also, in some cases, solving the relaxed non-integer linear program and rounding the solution off to 0/1 may produce a valid solution, in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

We could choose the first lg 2N rows out of the 2N strings, and then since 2^(lg 2N) = 2N, in a lot of cases there shouldn't be very many ways to assign the N columns so that the prefixes of length lg 2N are respected. Then all the rows are filled in so they can be checked to see if a solution has been found. We can also try assigning more rows in the beginning, and fill in different combinations of rows besides the initial rows. (e.g. we can try filling in contiguous rows starting anywhere in the grid).

Running time for assigning lg 2N rows out of 2N strings is O((2N)^(lg 2N)) = O(2^((lg 2N)^2)), which grows slower than 2^N. Assigning columns to match the prefixes is the part that's the hardest to predict run time. If a prefix occurs K times among the assigned rows, and there are M remaining strings that have the prefix, then the number of assignments for this prefix is M*(M-1)*...*(M-K+1). The total number of possible column assignments is the product of these terms over all prefixes that occur among the rows. If this gets to be too large, the number of rows initially assigned can be increased. But it's hard to predict the worst-case run time unless an assumption is made like the NxN grid is filled in randomly.